# WordPress при создании записи перекидывает на редактирование товара

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-плагины

На WordPress при создании записи перекидывает на редактирование товара.
Как понять, откуда пошла эта проблема? Как ее решить или диагностировать?

При отключении WooCommerce получается добавить запись.
Но это не метод решения проблемы. Может, нужно почистить кеш или
после установки других плагинов сбились какие-либо настройки?
Подскажите, кто знает, что сделать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: И что потом делать ? Как диагностировать проблему и решить ее ?

Comment: Не использовать плагин, который создает проблему.

Comment: Это не решает проблему.  В том то и суть Что Нужно уметь диагностировать проблему

Comment: Именно это (выяснение проблемного плагина) и есть диагностика проблемы. Далее - все вопросы к производителю плагина.

Comment: Хотите полное понимание причины - xdebug в руки и вперед.

Comment: Спасибо. Вам за ответы. Буду еще искать варианты решения